# Is it possible to turn .shp or .tif files into a grid with values using R?

Tags: r, gis, raster

I am new to rastor data (like really new). I want to take rastor data and turn it into a giant matrix or table in R with each cell representing the data from the layer. Is this possible?

I have a .shp file and read that into R.

Comment: You would get better answers to your question if you provide more information.  What packages are you using to read in your shapefile?  what do you want to do with the data once it's converted to a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

A raster is a giant matrix with each item representing a cell from the layer. Once you have a raster object in R, you can manipulate it like a matrix.

Shapefiles (.shp) hold spatial vector data rather raster data, you can convert from vector to raster.  Look into packages `raster` or `stars` for handling rasters in R. `raster::rasterize()` will convert spatial objects to raster.  Without more information (e.g. is your shapefile polygons, lines, or points? How do you want to summarize your vector data as a raster?) it's difficult to provide better guidance.

There are some really good tutorials for working with geospatial data in R, including https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/ and the vignette's for the `sf` package.